# compile one sass/compass file into multiple css files

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am looking fo the following:

Lets say i have a main.scss which contains al my css.

At the top of the file i have the following line:

```
@import "partials/vars";
```

This contains all my variables that i'm using in my main.scss (like colors, padding, etc...)

The problem is that my application will be used by multiple clients. Each with their own colour schemes etc.

So what i would like is the easiest method (if there is one) to say:

i have my main file and i compile it to eg:

company1.css
company2.css
company3.css

Each of them containing the same css code but with their own colour scheme.

if its company1 then it should import 'partials/company1Vars.scss
company2 loads company2vars.scss
etc

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SASS output from one sass file to multiple css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694609/sass-output-from-one-sass-file-to-multiple-css-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how many companies you have but if it's not some insane number, you could probably have:

company1Styles.scss
company2Styles.scss
company3Styles.scss
etc.

Each of those would contain a line like

```
@import "partials/_company1Vars.scss"
@import "_screen.scss"; // contains everything else
```

or

```
@import "partials/_company2Vars.scss"
@import "_screen.scss"; // contains everything else
```

You could change the variables independently of everything else in your project and get different outputs.

Comment: You should not include the underscores in the `@import` statements according to the docs: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials

Comment: @HaralanDobrev I'm not sure that's true, can you specify the part of the docs that say that you should not include the underscore? Seems like a style thing.